# Create a mesh ellipse

Tags: modeling

How do I draw an ellipse in Blender? I am a new user (actually VERY old user) and need a simple question like the one above answered.

Comment: You could add a circle  (SHIFT + "A") and scale it down on one axis (SHIFT + "X" "Y" or "Z"

Answer (score 4):

Add a sphere and scale it in a single axis.
[image]